# GORM not closing connection outside of grails controlled classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a method on grails 2.4.3 (I removed the parts that does not matter):

```
@Override
protected void handleAnswerEvent(Message event) {
     def con = Contrato.find("from Contrato where ? in elements(telefones)", [tel])
}
```

But this method is running in a thread outside of the grails managed classes (I'm not very sure that what I'm saying here makes sense...). The point is is after a while it gives me:

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [http-bio-8080-exec-254] Timeout: Pool empty.
```

Changing the max connections does not solve the problem of the leak. What am I supposed to do to grails to close this automatically or is there other way to solve this?

Comment: could you please share your DataSource.groovy. I want to see settings in it.

Comment: I could @Anshul but I dont think it has anything to do with it besides the                 maxActive = 50, minIdle = 5, maxIdle = 25. But that is not the problem... the problem is the fact that connections are not closing and staying alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look of these links, I guess they may help you to solve your problem

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11043

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11700

Thanks.

[Update]

Issue is something related to connection pool leak problems. Using GroovySQL outside of transaction context leaks connections if you don't explicitly close the the connection (GRAILS-5454 fixed that in transactional context, but the problem remains outside of transactions).
take a look of these links, I guess they may help you to solve your problem. Issue have been resolved in grails 2.4.4

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/2797

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/3017

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/2776

Thanks.

Comment: links are broken and this does not qualify as an answer

Comment: @NoIdeaForName - Links are broken because grails jira have moved to Git, I have updated the links with some cause. Thanks